# Close Animation On Body Click

Tags: jquery, animation

How can I close an animation when i press on body , not the element that make the animation appear/dissapear?

```js
$('#btt').click(function() {
  $('.box').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #00000025;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btt">PressIt</button>
<div class="box"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c7wt9jz6/17/

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

1. Use `slideUp()` when the `body` is clicked
2. Stop propagating the click event when you click `.box` element so that the `body` click is not simulated, using `e.stopPropagation();`

   ```js
   $('#btt').click(function(e) {
     $('.box').slideToggle('slow');
     e.stopPropagation();
   });
   $('body').click(function(){
     $('.box').slideUp();
   });
   ```

   ```css
   .box {
     width: 200px;
     height: 300px;
     background-color: #00000025;
     display: none;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <button id="btt">PressIt</button>
   <div class="box"></div>
   ```

Comment: Thaks.And I want that when I press on that div nothing happens, i need to control the body event when I press the div ?

Comment: @Valentin no. The event is directly on body so you can click anywhere in body

Comment: And there is a way to do that?Something like Facebook message animation(that in the top of the page)